# How to deploy TensorFlow probability model

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, tensorflow-probability

I want to use structural time series models from the TensorFlow probability library to model my time series.
I'm not sure how to push the model into production so that it can run online.
My first idea is to split time series into a chunk (season) train model on this chunk, push the model into production and retrain model whenever new data arrive (same as Arima models).

Is it a good approach?
I will be very grateful for all hints.